# Apple's Notes App - Object archives, SQL or Core Data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, data-structures

As an exercise, I'm trying to rebuild the Notes App and was wondering what the best file system for a notes app would be?

I guess these are the requirements:

1) Not all notes should be loaded at the same time (lazy loading); i.e. I don't want to have all notes in one huge NSMutableDictionary or NSMutableArray -- so ideally, I guess that a separate file for each note would be a good idea

2) Notes should be searchable. Again, I have no idea what is best suited, but my feeling is that searching through a huge string containing all notes may not be the best solution.

3) Export. I guess this is not really that important when thinking about the data structure, but if I wanted to do a dropBox or iCloud sync, is there any file system which is more suitable than another? Especially if I wanted the user to be able to edit separate txt files for each note they've done?

Any ideas and suggestions where to start would be very much welcome! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data with spotlight export will be your best option.

The real trick is make the model support detailed searches with things like keyword entities and linked-list type structures. These are a lot of work but they can make searching almost instantaneous.